# Qt::Popup window type automatically closes on X11/i3.. is this behavior guaranteed?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

Is it guaranteed that when the user clicks outside of a popup in the parent window, the popup closes and/or can we modify that behavior or influence that somehow? I see that behavior in X11 with the i3 window manager.

I would like to have the functionality that popup seems to provide: Modal with regard to the parent (i.e if the user clicks somewhere in the parent window.. the popup won't let it through, but instead trigger an event that I can handle myself.. for example by closing the popup explicitly).

**Edit**

I found that the usual "closeEvent" can be used to reject the closing of the popup. However it's still mysterious to me whether or not the "modal"-y behavior is guaranteed and the auto-closing is guaranteed.